# Dividir data frame pela primeira linha dele mesmo

Tags: r, dataframe

Estou tentando criar um número índice a partir de um data frame. Gostaria de dividir cada coluna pelo primeiro número sem precisar fazer a divisão coluna a coluna.

Apenas como exemplo, o df seria:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Aaron", "Blake"), Jan = c(2, 5), Feb = c(4, 6), Mar = c(3, 4))
```

Fazendo coluna a coluna, por exemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF1$Fev/first(DF1$Fev)*100
```

o resultado é o esperado:

```
[1] 100 150
```

Porém fazendo

```
DF1[,-1]/first(DF1[,-1])*100
```

obtenho

```
  Jan Fev Mar
1 100 200 150
2 100 120  80
```

O adequado seria

```
   Name Jan Fev      Mar
1 Aaron 100 100 100.0000
2 Blake 250 150 133.3333
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Vou trabalhar com um data frame com muitas colunas em breve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de fazer o que quer. Vou usar duas delas.

- Com o `tidyverse`.
- Só com R base.

Em ambas vou trabalhar com cópias de `DF1`.
Primeiro `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF2 <- DF1
DF2[-1] <- DF2[-1] %>%
  mutate_all(funs(./first(.)*100))

DF2
#   Name Jan Feb      Mar
#1 Aaron 100 100 100.0000
#2 Blake 250 150 133.3333
```

Agora R base.

```
DF3 <- DF1
DF3[-1] <- lapply(DF3[-1], function(x) x/x[1]*100)

DF3
#   Name Jan Feb      Mar
#1 Aaron 100 100 100.0000
#2 Blake 250 150 133.3333
```

Verificação final.

```
identical(DF2, DF3)
#[1] TRUE
```